# Disable GIF autoplay

Tags: javascript, onload, animated-gif, autoplay

I'm looking for a way to automaticly disable autoplay for the animated gifs posted on my little chat-site (php-based)
I think I'm getting close, but I'm all out of ideas with this script:

```
<script>
myVid=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
function disableAutoplay()
  { 
  myVid.autoplay=false;
  myVid.load();
  } 
</script> 
</head>
<body onload="disableAutoplay();">
```

Objective: Prevent posted GIF's (animated) from automaticly starting onload.
Thanks

**Update**

Able to make it work with jquery but->
Trying to figure out a cleaner way to do this, that suggestion about mouseover-events got me thinking, perhaps something like this would be possible?

```
        $com  = $_POST['txt'];
        $count = strlen($com);
        $com = stripslashes($com);
        $alter1 = array(".gif");
        $com = str_ireplace($alter1, ".gif autoplay=false onmouseover **MAKE IT PLAY**", $com);
```

I'm on thin ice now, not even sure that it's possible to control GIFs like this with HTML-tags

Comment: U mean something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19990234/961695 ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the autoplay attribute, but given that `myvid` may be populated before the document is fully loaded, you probably want to move that first line inside your function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop a gif animation onload, on mouseover start the activation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818003/stop-a-gif-animation-onload-on-mouseover-start-the-activation)

Comment: @amphetamachine - Well, that is a good solution if the GIFs are in a folder on my system, wich these ain't, the names are dynamic.... so, it's a good lead, but it doesn't help me much..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is native way of stopping, but what you can do is just put static png/jpeg picture which is starting point of your gif picture. Then when you hit play, replace that static image with animated gif one.

Update:

```
<script>
window.document.onload = function(e){ 
   var myVid=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
   var gifPath=myVid.src;
   myVid.src='/static/image/path.png'; 
   // now you can use your gif depending on business logic
}    
</script>
```

PS: the code was not tested... this is for just showing a pseudo code.

Comment: Oh, didn't think of that. Thank you :) Gonna give it a shot.