# Enable GIF autoplay on GitHub README

Tags: github, markdown, gif, github-flavored-markdown

**Question:** How to enable GIF autoplay on GitHub README.md?

For a few days, I've noticed README GIF aren't playing auto automatically. It was playing before.

Through search, I've found theses, cannot find the solution.

- [add a GIF to a Markdown file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34341808/10157127)
- [Disable GIF autoplay using JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432281/disable-gif-autoplay)

**Minimal—Reproducible example**
Test markdown file; link took from [above question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34341808/10157127)

```markdown
![Alt Text](https://media.giphy.com/media/vFKqnCdLPNOKc/giphy.gif)
<br>
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/vFKqnCdLPNOKc/giphy.gif" width="40" height="40" />
```

Provide result on GitHub README

[image]

**Expected output on README.md**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check you [GitHub accessibility settings](https://github.com/settings/accessibility).

Since [May 2022](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-05-19-option-to-prevent-animated-images-from-playing-automatically/), there is an option to prevent animated images from playing automatically.

Set it to Enable.