# Animated gif player with rewind function

Tags: javascript, animation, animated-gif

I need to make a tool that would be able to act like a video player on animated gif file. Need to be able to rewind to selected frame, display frame count, pause, play animation... Is it possible to do it via javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting single frames from animgif to canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645274/extracting-single-frames-from-animgif-to-canvas)

Comment: @zero298 I don't want to extract frames...

Comment: True, but you are trying to directly manipulate what frames are displayed in an animated GIF and the accepted answer's lead response is: "Sorry, the short answer is that JavaScript has no way of controlling the current frame of an Animated GIF."  It does go on to give some cludgy ways of doing it through extracting the GIF frames and playing them on a canvas.  I guess it's not a direct duplicate, but very much related.  Sorry for marking as such.

Comment: "Sorry, the short answer is that JavaScript has no way of controlling the current frame of an Animated GIF." - that's an answer that I was looking for :)