# Split gif frames client side

Tags: javascript, html, client-side, animated-gif

I'm working on a little project website that will manipulate animated .GIF files, in which the user has to select a specific frame and submit their selection. The GIF and selected frame number will then be sent to the server and the server will process the GIF and information.

I want it to be as efficient as possible as the processing of the GIF is already quite taxing on the server and splitting the GIF client-side should save on some of the server's resources.

I've looked around for some solutions, but was unable to find any concrete answers based on my needs. 
Any client-side scripting tech which doesn't require a plugin is acceptable, though the only two I can think of that could possibly perform such a task would be JavaScript and perhaps HTML5(?)..

Ideally I would want all the frames to be loaded into a container, but I could see loading the frames into a 'player', through which you could navigate frames work.

As you can tell I'm not too seasoned in web languages and their capabilities yet, so any pointers would be appreciated.

My question is, is it possible? If yes, could you point me into the right direction?

If not, I will plan to send the GIF to the server, split it and then send the frames back to the client.

Comment: It can be done using the Canvas API http://html5doctor.com/an-introduction-to-the-canvas-2d-api/

Comment: @Jonas Grumann Thank you for your comment, I just wanted to add, the .GIF is 'uploaded'/added by the users their selves. Would this still be possible with the html5 canvas api?

Comment: So you want the users to be able to upload a gif, select a frame, and send it to the server?

Comment: Take a look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645274/extracting-single-frames-from-animgif-to-canvas