# How do i get a particular gif Frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, gif, animated-gif

I just wanted to ask, is there any way to get one frame out of complete gif (for example, the 164 image in the animation) using javascript / jQuery?

For being more clear, by using it, will i be able to make a slider image library, which every image in there is the next image in the gif animation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js

Comment: https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js

Comment: look at [SO Can you control GIF animation with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385203/can-you-control-gif-animation-with-javascript) or [SO Extracting single frames from animgif to canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645274/extracting-single-frames-from-animgif-to-canvas)